# How to optimize this code in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have 3 models **source.rb** belongs to **category.rb** and **feed_entry.rb** belongs to source.rb.

I need to display feed_entries in category

> **Category name**
>
> FeedEntry 1
>
> FeedEntry 2
>
> FeedEntry 3

Now it looks like this

```
class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    @sources = @category.sources.all
  end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<%= @category.name %></h4>

<% @sources.each do |source| %>
  <% source.feed_entries.each do |feed_entry| %>
    <%= link_to feed_entry.name, feed_entry %>
    <%= feed_entry.source.title %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

this is very slow

I use mongoid 4, rails 4

Models

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  has_many :sources, dependent: :destroy
end

class FeedEntry
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  belongs_to :source, touch: true
  validates :source_id, presence: true
end

class Source
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :title, type: String
  has_many :feed_entries, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :category, touch: true
end
```

Comment: The usual way to optimize MongoDB queries is to rearrange your schema through denormalization and embedding. So what do your models look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

In Category.rb add feed_entries

```
class Category
  def feed_entries
    FeedEntry.in(source_id: sources.map(&:id))
  end
end
```

and in show.html.erb

```
<% @category.feed_entries.includes(:source).each do |feed_entry| %>
  <%= link_to feed_entry.name, feed_entry %>
  <%= feed_entry.source.title %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Some thinks to know :

- Never use `.all`, unless you know size of result data. Always use pagination or limit.
- When you have a loop like your `each` in view, this will call queries like this :

  - Give me a category
  - Give me its sources
  - Give me feed entries for source 1
  - Give me feed entries for source 2
  - ....

You should eagler load your association like this :

```
@sources = @category.sources.limit(20).includes(:feed_entries)
```

It will to theses queries :

- Give me a category
- Give me its sources
- Give me feed entries for theses sources

If you don't want any information about categories (like I think), you should add a relation to your model :

```
Class Category
  has_many :sources
  has_many :feed_entries, :through => :sources
end
```

Then call in your controller

```
@feed_entries = @category.feed_entries
```

This will do only ONE query :

- Give me category
- Give me the feed entries of the category

That's it !

Comment: Thanks for the answer but mongoid doesn't have has_many :through association